# rsDriver() in Rselenium doesn't work

Tags: rselenium

I have updated my r to latest version and I installed Rselenium again.

I try to use rsDriver but it has a problem with port 4567. Same like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42316527/probem-running-rselenium-with-rsdriver)

Error trace back:

```
rd <-rsDriver(verbose =TRUE, browser = 'phantomjs', version = "3.4.0")
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking geckodriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking phantomjs versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
Error in wdman::selenium(port = port, verbose = verbose, version = version,  : 
  Selenium server signals port = 4567 is already in use.
```

I don't know what else to try. Is there anything I can do?

if I try to run verbose=false I receive this error:

```
Selenium message:The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\username\Documents

Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: java.lang.IllegalStateException
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

The RSelenium exist in `C:\Users\username\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\RSelenium`
and under this path `C:\Users\username\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\wdman\yaml` I see the seleniumserver.yml files

What is going wrong? I tried also a past version of R but again the problem is the same.

Comment: Try a different port. Use the `port` argument.

Comment: @jdharrison I tried a different option but the problem still exist

Comment: Sometimes it helps to change the number of the port...
You can try whatever number...

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue and set up the port manually:

```
rd = rsDriver(port = 4567L, browser = "chrome", version = "latest", chromever = "latest")
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. My chrome version was newer than the available versions in Selenium. In the end it worked by installing firefox AND setting the chrome version on NULL.

```
 rs_driver <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", 
                     chromever = NULL, 
                     verbose = FALSE, 
                     port = 4567L)
```